# Wireguard on a DigitalOcean Droplet not allowing ssh, vnc, or smb

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard, digital-ocean

EDIT 3/15/22: Config info added at the end of this question
I had a WireGuard VPN on a Google Cloud VPN but due to networking fees setup a new one on DigitalOcean. For some reason, I cannot SSH, VNC, or use SMB across any of the devices, but my public IP address seems to be working.

Is this a DigitalOcean related issue or any recommendations for troubleshooting?

This is an example of an error I get when trying to SSH into another device that is a peer to the DigitalOcean Ubuntu Droplet:

```
ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.5 port 22: Operation timed out
```

wg0.conf on the DigitalOcean server:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
SaveConfig = true
PostUp = ufw route allow in on wg0 out on eth0
PostUp = iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = ip6tables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PreDown = ufw route delete allow in on wg0 out on eth0
PreDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PreDown = ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = eHXOyd8**REMOVED FOR SECURITY**xMO9mlc=

[Peer]
PublicKey = wk6iHe+FiJhIV+wLxeCVLyWdT/WV8xrLmeHI39m5v2o=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32
Endpoint = 104.228.167.16:51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = /OEck40Kjc15a3JzePkf9wmlMw+Sdzgaauhfzt/3LkM=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.3/32
Endpoint = 104.228.167.16:55239

[Peer]
PublicKey = CgHsJnocl8CkpD0c4rqFPmOBbpNB8Wpx0hy6J0YhBj0=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.4/32
Endpoint = 104.228.167.16:59555

[Peer]
PublicKey = wxW/6x/M8msXWqahcAR7OjpZbXsZta18qMHGMvbKaRg=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.5/32
Endpoint = 104.228.167.16:52628
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Result of running `sudo ufw status`:

```
root@wireguard:~# sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
51820/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
51820/udp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

Anywhere on eth0           ALLOW FWD   Anywhere on wg0           
Anywhere (v6) on eth0      ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6) on wg0
```

My iMac Config (trying to SSH, VNC, and SMB into the raspberry pi):
[Screenshot of the App Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG7zr.png)

And Raspberry Pi (network server) wg0.conf file:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = 0B26+xT9D4ZxOD23IeOPvh7gApOL5ES5NdXES/l7Lkk=
Address = 10.0.0.5

[Peer]
PublicKey = uj4QIUv4k40HK0nCGAtPKx8BYLUtWK8cTvLGOADkzx4=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 142.93.113.242:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

And a screenshot of my DigitalOcean Dashboard:
[DigitalOcean VM Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tzfj.png)

Comment: You mean like one WG client accessing another? Post your confs please.

Comment: 10.0.0.5 isn’t a public IP address. You have to use the public IP address to connect a droplet to another droplet

Comment: @TomYan Added. Yes, your are correct. I am trying to have one client access another.

Comment: Most likely it's because you didn't allow "from wg0 to wg0" forwarding additionally in ufw. Something like `ufw route allow in on wg0 out on wg0`, I suppose (not familiar with ufw).

Comment: @TomYan That worked. Thank you. Yes, I'm not familiar with ufw. May I ask why this was not an issue on GCP?

Comment: @JacobMiller it really just depends on how the forward chain is configured out-of-the-box. Firewall allow rules are like "exceptions", if the firewall is not configured with a "default case" that blocks traffics, then you don't any allow rules. (There's also a chance that GCP instances do not even come with any firewall configuration / frontend in effect / running by default.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a user in the comments, allowing the firewall to route traffic through the VPN interface fixed the issue.